# Iterate through directories and copy all files from within any subdirectories to a new directory with the same name

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'll try to explain this as best I can. I have a few hundred directories, each one contains a handful of other sub-directories, and files scattered throughout each of those sub-directories. I don't need or want any of the sub-directories, only the files, but the directory names must remain the same. So essentially going from:

```
$ source tree

├── sub1
│   └── sub1.1
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
├── sub2
    └── sub2.1
        └── sub2.1.1
            ├── file1
            └── file2
```

to new directory:

```
├── sub1
│     ├── file1
│     └── file2
├── sub2
      ├── file1
      └── file2
```

All that really matters is that the folders, here sub1 & sub2, have the same name, all sub folders within them are not copied, and the files are all copied to the new folder. I have been trying to figure this one out for about 2 hours and cannot seem to do it.

I am using bash, and I know this is possible, I just don't know how to get there. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe `find` to `xargs`, executing `cp`:

```bash
find sub1/* -type f -mindepth 2 -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t /sub1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this command will give you a list of all files located within subfolders of your specified root folder:

`find ./*/ -type f -iname "*.*"`

You could then use basename to extract the file name itself, then iterate over that output using rsync (better than cp because it checks its work).  Something like this perhaps:

`rsync -aiSP /source/"${filepath}" /destination/"${basefilename}"`

Structurally something like this:

```
for filepath in "$( find ./*/ -type f -iname "*.*" )" ; do 
    basefilename="$( basename "${filepath}" )" 
    rsync -aiSP /source/"${filepath}" /destination/"${basefilename}" 
done
```

That code won't work due to the way find is parsed, but something like this should do what you are asking.

The key take-aways from me would be the `find ./*/` which avoids loose files in the root folder and only seeks files in any subfolders, and the use of rsync which I say works better than using cp.

Let me know if you have questions.

I think I would explore a solution along these lines:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filepath; do 
    basefilename="$( basename "${filepath}" )" 
    rsync -aiSP /source/"${filepath}" /destination/"${basefilename}" 
done < <( find ./*/ -type f -iname "*.*" -print0 )
```

That code is more likely to work as-is.  Enjoy!

Comment: It can be done directly with `find` with action `find sub1 -type f -exec cp -iv "{}" sub1 \;`

Comment: `find` in `for filepath in find ./*/ -type f -iname "*.*" ;` is not a command. If you meant `for filepath in $(find ./*/ -type f -iname "*.*") ;` then it's [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  I have updated the find command and quoted it as you are correct that is what I meant.  I looked over the six reasons at the beginning of the link you provided and perhaps you can help me understand why objections would remain since this looks like clean and unmolested output:  ```filepath="$( find ./*/ -type f -iname "*.*" )" ```.

Comment: When you double-quote, there is no splitting at all. See the linked article where it says `You can't simply double-quote the substitution either`.

Comment: Oh, right.  So the output of find would be one long string.  Yeah, that ```for``` construct would not work as expected.  I would have to run the output through something to cut by newline or similar.  Very good.  I suppose a construct using -exec would be better.  I added a note for any reader about what is important in my response.  Tell me more about not being able to quote substitutions because I'm not clear what you are saying about that.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I added some additional notes to help anyone move in a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to copy the entire tree to a new location, `cd` there and rearrange the new directory tree. But a file like `./sub2/foo/foo` would be problematic: it should become `./sub2/foo`, but this name is taken by a directory which cannot be removed before we move the file.

Let's build a new tree while copying then.

---

#### Solution for `bash`, using non-portable options

```
#!/bin/bash

srce="/source/directory"
trgt="/target/directory"

shopt -s nullglob dotglob

mkdir -p -- "$trgt" || exit 1

# in case trgt is relative
cd -- "$trgt" || exit 1
trgt="$PWD"
cd -- "$OLDPWD" || exit 2

cd -- "$srce" || exit 2

find . -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -exec cp -t "$trgt" -- {} +

for d in ./*; do
   [ -d "$d" ] && mkdir -p -- "$trgt/$d" \
   && find "$d" ! -type d -exec cp -t "$trgt/$d" -- {} +
done
```

Notes:

- Non-directories that exist directly in the source directory will be copied directly to the target directory.
- Subdirectories without files (if any) will be created anyway.
- Existing content in the target directory may make the code misbehave.
- Name conflicts (if any) are not taken care of.
- Double dash explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618).
- Non-portable fragments: `shopt`, `find -maxdepth`, `cp -t`.

---

#### Portable solution

<sup>(I mean I think it's portable. If it's not, please leave a comment.)</sup>

```
#!/bin/sh

srce="/source/directory"
trgt="/target/directory"

mkdir -p -- "$trgt" || exit 1

# in case trgt is relative
cd -- "$trgt" || exit 1
trgt="$PWD"
cd -- "$OLDPWD" || exit 2

cd -- "$srce" || exit 2

find . \
   ! -type d \
   \( \( ! -path '*/*/*' -exec cp -- {} "$trgt/" \; \) \
   -o \( -path '*/*/*' -exec sh -c '
      trgt="$1"
      shift
      for f do
         sbdr="${f#./}"
         sbdr="${sbdr%%/*}"
         mkdir -p -- "$trgt/$sbdr" && cp -- "$f" "$trgt/$sbdr"
      done
   ' find-sh "$trgt" {} + \) \)
```

Notes:

- This approach is substantially different, it doesn't use `for` loop.
- Non-directories that exist directly in the source directory will be copied directly to the target directory.
- Subdirectories without files won't be created. Here the two solutions differ.
- Existing content in the target directory may make the code misbehave.
- `mkdir -p` is used excessively. With more logic one can certainly reduce the number of `mkdir`s but I chose to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).
- `cp` is used very inefficiently: one process per file.
- Name conflicts (if any) are not taken care of. The two different solutions may preserve different conflicting files.

---

Yet another approach would be to find subdirectories with one `find` and run extra `find`s in them to find files. It's possible but tricky. Compare [this answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560768/108618), the fragment "How to properly run find on results on another find?"

Comment: Thanks so much! I am having a little trouble following your first (non portable option) but it did indeed work! I will review the other options as well, this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit more complex, but perhaps easier to follow?

```
> tree
.
├── filebot.txt
├── test
│   ├── dir1
│   │   ├── foo1
│   │   └── foo2
│   └── dir2
│       └── foo3
├── test2
│   ├── dir2
│   │   └── foo3
│   └── dir3
│       ├── foo1
│       └── foo2
└── test3
    ├── dir1
    │   ├── foo1
    │   └── foo3
    └── dir3
        └── foo2
```

### command

```
> mapfile -t files < <(find . -mindepth 2 -type f );\
 for FILE in ${files[*]}; do \
   mv "$FILE" $(sed -n 's/\(.\/.*\/\).*\//\1/p' <<< "$FILE");\
 done
```

### explination

- mapfile: create array of files to process
- for loop: process each file in array
- mv/cp/rsync: action per file

  - sed: capture base directory name and strip subs.

### results

```
mv ./test/dir1/foo1 ./test/foo1
mv ./test/dir1/foo2 ./test/foo2
mv ./test/dir2/foo3 ./test/foo3
mv ./test2/dir2/foo3 ./test2/foo3
mv ./test2/dir3/foo1 ./test2/foo1
mv ./test2/dir3/foo2 ./test2/foo2
mv ./test3/dir1/foo1 ./test3/foo1
mv ./test3/dir1/foo3 ./test3/foo3
mv ./test3/dir3/foo2 ./test3/foo2
```

You can clean the empty directories after with

```
find -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: How about `./test2/foo2/foo2`?

Comment: The command is only capturing the the first directory name and stripping any subs, so it will also handle files with same dir name.

Comment: Well… I expect `mv ./test2/foo2/foo2 ./test2/foo2`. But in this case the last argument is an existing directory. What happens then? Imagine there are `./test/foo/bar` and `./test/bar/foo`. What happens then?